# Frequency counter undefined/power of 2 not equal

Tags: javascript

So the problem is 2 arrays:

```
[1,2,2,4];
[1,4,4,16];
```

Check if the items from the first array have duplicates in the second array.

```
const counterNumber = (arr1,arr2) => {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false

    let counter1 = {}
    let counter2 = {}

    for (let val of arr1){
        counter1[val] = ( counter1[val] || 0 )+ 1
    }

    for (let val of arr2){
         counter2[val] = ( counter2[val] || 0 )+ 1
    }

    for(let key in counter1){
        if(!(key ** 2 in counter2)) return false     
        if(counter2[key ** 2] !== counter1[key]) return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Now this is  working but I don't understand this line

```
if(counter2[key ** 2] !== counter1[key]) return false
```

How it's this not returning false? first array has  1,2,2,4 and second array 1,4,4,16.

for the first array, after storing the values in one object, the object will have the keys 1,2,3.
In the for in loop

```
counter2[key **2] is  counter[1 ** 2] / counter[1]  // counter1[1] 
counter2[key ** 2] is counter[ 2 ** 2] / counter[4] // counter1[2]
counte2[key ** 3] is counter{ 3 ** 2] / counter[9]  // counter1[3]


these are not === so therefore it should return false but instead if i console.log it gives me undefined and the return true appears.
```

Comment: can you take the code into snippets and add what "*these are not === so therefore it should return false but instead if i console.log it gives me undefined and the return true appears.*" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the last for loop

`counter1` is

```js
const counter1 = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  4: 1
}
```

`counter2` is

```js
const counter2 = {
  1: 1,
  4: 2,
  16: 1
}
```

Here is a table describing different variables based on values in `arr1`

```
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
| #1 | value in arr1  | 1 | 2 | 4 |
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
| #2 | counter1 key   | 1 | 2 | 4 |
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
| #3 | counter2 key   | 1 | 4 |16 |
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
| #4 | counter1 value | 1 | 2 | 1 |
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
| #5 | counter2 value | 1 | 2 | 1 |
+----+----------------+---+---+---+
```

The line below is checking the frequency of values in both arrays.

```js
if(counter2[key ** 2] !== counter1[key]) return false
```

If you look at the table it is comparing row #4 & #5;

The code can be refactored to be clearer like this

```js
const counterNumber = (arr1,arr2) => {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false

    let counter1 = {}
    let counter2 = {}

    for (let val of arr1){
        counter1[val] = ( counter1[val] || 0 )+ 1
    }

    for (let val of arr2){
         counter2[val] = ( counter2[val] || 0 )+ 1
    }

    for(let key in counter1){
        if(!hasMatchingSquareNumber(key, counter2)) return false     
        if(!hasMatchingSquareNumberCount(key, counter1, counter2)) return false
    }

    return true
}

const hasMatchingSquareNumber = (value, counter2) => {
    const valueToSquare =  value ** 2;
    return valueToSquare in counter2; 
}

const hasMatchingSquareNumberCount = (value, counter1, counter2) =>  {
    const valueToSquare =  value ** 2;
    return counter2[valueToSquare] === counter1[value];
}
```

Comment: now i realise i was confusing keys with values in counter2 thank you !